# Proving that the solution set of $ax+by+cz=0$ and $dx+ey+fz=0$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

I have a question here which says:

"The solution set of:

$$ax+by+cz=0$$
$$dx+ey+fz=0$$

is a line in $\mathbb{R^3}$"

I am supposed to show that this is true or false. If it's true, I have to explain why and if it's false, I have to explain why it's false.

I don't think it's true. We COULD have a line if the planes intersected but if $a,b,c$ are scalar multiples of $d,e,f$, then we would just have the same plane since there are infinitely many solutions. Is that the right should process or did I mess up my reasoning?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :) .

Comment: There's also the possibility that the planes are parallel and therefore never intersect, in which case there are no solutions.

Comment: @RobertHoward actually no solution is NOT a possibility here because of the homogeneous system, so either a line or a plane are the only possible solutions.

Comment: @AnuragA You make a good point; I was too quick with my earlier comment!

Comment: I caught it though so no worries!

Comment: @RobertHoward I’m astonished that your comment got three upvotes!

Comment: @amd So am I! ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When absolutely nothing is provided about $a,b,c,d,e,f$ then for one you may even just take say all of them to be equal to zero, and then the system of solutions is the whole of $\mathbb R^3$, which is not a line.

Of course, a plane is also obtainable : it is obtained exactly when the ratios $d:a,e:b,f:c$ are the same (else, the planes would not be parallel and hence would intersect at a line passing through zero). Then, the equations $ax+by+cz = 0$ and $dx+ey+fz = 0$ describe the same plane. This is clearly seen for example with $a,b,c,d,e,f$ all equal to $1$,  or say $a,b,c=1$, $d,e,f = 2$. So, obviously the statement given can be false.

Note , however, that a solution must exist. This is because of the rank-nullity theorem, applied on  the linear transformation $(x,y,z) \to (ax+by+cz,dx+ey+fz)$. This is a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$. It has rank atmost $2$, therefore nullity at least one i.e. the null space has at least one line.